# Styling excel in Laravel with Laravel Excel

Tags: phpspreadsheet, laravel-excel

Learning Laravel, I face now Excel export.

Searching in the Intenet Laravel Excel (docs.laravel-excel.com) seems to be the better choice, but I'm findind it very difficult to style the sheets (colors, fonts, sizes, etc.)

I'm using global event listeners in my AppServiceProvider:

```
Sheet::listen(AfterSheet::class, function () {
        Sheet::macro('color_tab', function (Sheet $sheet, string $color) {
            $sheet->getDelegate()->getTabColor()->setRGB($color);
        });
});
```

And then I use it in my Export class:

```
...
public function __construct($color) {
    $this->color = $color;
}
...
use RegistersEventListeners;
...
public static function afterSheet(AfterSheet $event) {
    // this is an error because it's a static method!
    $event->sheet->color_tab($this->color);
}
```

The problem is that I have to color the tab whit the color given in the constructor, but I can't because all these method for styling the Excel are static.

How can I do this?

Is there another good library to export Excel? With an easier way of do the styling.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I decided to use directly PhpSpreadSheet library whithout using wrapper Laravel Excel